# Finding and replacing nodes in a Linked List

Tags: java, linked-list

I need to be able to find and replace user information in a Linked List. I have been reading several tutorials and examples but it doesn't seem to work. The set method used for linked lists isn't working. So I am wondering if I am implementing it wrong or what. Any help would be great. Also just FYI my linked list is loaded from a file and basically its just user information with each element on a different line.

i.e.

```
        int index = account.indexOf(hobby);
        account.set(index, "New String");
```

Code:

```
private void jButtonP1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    LinkedList<Account> account = new LinkedList<Account>();
    //user information
    String username = jTextFieldP3.getText();
    String password = jPasswordFieldP1.getText();
    String email = jTextFieldP4.getText();
    String name = jTextFieldP1.getText();
    String breed = (String) jComboBoxP4.getSelectedItem();
    String gender = (String) jComboBoxP3.getSelectedItem();
    String age = (String) jComboBoxP1.getSelectedItem();
    String state = (String) jComboBoxP2.getSelectedItem();
    String hobby = jTextFieldP2.getText();
    //combo boxes
    String passchange = (String) jComboBoxP13.getSelectedItem();
    String emailchange = (String) jComboBoxP14.getSelectedItem();
    String namechange = (String) jComboBoxP6.getSelectedItem();
    String breedchange = (String) jComboBoxP7.getSelectedItem();
    String genderchange = (String) jComboBoxP8.getSelectedItem();
    String agechange = (String) jComboBoxP9.getSelectedItem();
    String statechange = (String) jComboBoxP10.getSelectedItem();
    String hobbychange = (String) jComboBoxP11.getSelectedItem();
    String accountcancel = (String) jComboBoxP5.getSelectedItem();

    Account a = new Account(username, password, email, name, breed, gender, age, state, hobby);
    account.add(a);

    if(username.equals("") || password.equals("") || email.equals("")) // If password and username is empty > Do this >>>
    {
        jButtonP1.setEnabled(false);
        jTextFieldP3.setText("");
        jPasswordFieldP1.setText("");
        jTextFieldP4.setText("");
        jButtonP1.setEnabled(true);
        this.setVisible(true);

    }
    else if(a.onList(username) || a.onList(password) || a.onList(email))
    {
        int index = account.indexOf(hobby);
        account.set(index, "New String");
    }
    else
    {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int index = account.indexOf(hobby);
account.set(index, "New String");
```

The problem here si that indexOf() will return -1, because it searches for a String value inside a list with Account values.

You cannot search in the list by its elements' fields. You must search for that account manually and then set the hobby field:

```
for(Account acc : account){
    if(acc.getHobby().equals(hobby)){
        acc.setHobby("New String");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but lets say I found the username first. How would I iterate to each next node and just change them that way? mainly because the username will never change. I just want to have the option to change everything else.

Comment: Basically, when you create a List, you can expect the indexOf method to return meaningful values only for objects that you put previously inside. But you need to search the list for an element with certain value in certain field. List cannot do this for you. You must search manually by the for cycle and check every object inside. Then you can search by whatever you wish and modify whatever you wish.